# Assigning ids to relationships in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent model called "Customer". Customers have a one-to-many relationship with another model, "Image". I want to group the images owned by a customer so that I can assign them to different usecases - a customer would have a single image for a Logo, for instance, but many images for their gallery section.

How do I assign a usecase to a relationship in Laravel?

I'm thinking I will make an intermediary model called 'Usecase' and then access the images using the `hasManyThrough` method. Many relationships in my system need their usecases defined. I'm new to laravel, is this something that is already covered in the framework?

EDIT:
I also want to have Images assigned to Customers when they are not in use - so I could upload a bunch of images and say that they belong to a particular customer, but they aren't used anywhere until we assign a 'usecase' (ie, 'logo' or 'gallery'). This way I would have an image gallery of all the images that are assigned to the customer, and then a gallery for images assigned as 'gallery'. Bleh, does that make sense?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [spatie media library package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary). It allows you to "attach" images to models, and you can have multiple collections of images for each model (ex: a logo collection (which can enforce a single image), a gallery collection, etc). Even if you don't need its functionality, you can at least take a look at the code to see how they organized their models and relationships.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 approaches that I can think of to accomplish this.

1: You turn 'Logo' into a column on 'Customer' rather than a separate model and keep 'Image' for all gallery images.

2: You turn 'Logo' into a separate model, same for 'Customer' and 'Image'

3: You complicate your life and keep 'Logo' and gallery images as 'Image', then add a way to distinguish between the two (perhaps a flag: is_logo or an enum column: image_type).

If you ask me, the 2nd option is the most appealing.

Comment: Extending classes in Laravel is ok? Like if I go for option 2 I can still have my Image model, and then in my `logo` model I would `Logo extends Image`? Do I need to run  an artisan command to create that extended model? `php artisan make:model Logo extends Image`?

Comment: @AbrahamBrookes Yes, you can extend Image manually (I don't think artisan does it for you) - but why would you do that anyways?

Also try this: https://tighten.co/blog/extending-models-in-eloquent

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Polymorphic Relationships` relationship for this or separate the 2 images table

1. Customer
2. Logo
3. Image

Customer can have 1 logo 
Customer can have 1 or many Images

```
$customer = new Customer; 
$customer->with('images', 'logo')->get();
```

The will help you query in a group of result for all of your images and logo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 relations for the same model.

Model:

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function gallery()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class)->where('type', 'gallery');
    }

    public function logo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Image::class)->where('type', 'logo');
    }
}
```

Retrieving:

```
$customer = Customer::with(['gallery', 'logo'])->get();
```

Outputing:

```
@foreach($customer->gallery as $image)
    {{ $image->some_attribute }}
@endforeach

{{ $customer->logo->some_attribute }}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I'm afraid this produces issues with foreign keys.
You'll have something like 'customer_id, customer_id2'

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest approach is to...

1) Have a "UseCase" table that can define all types of use cases. This allows for simple scalability and readability without cluttering the image table with a bunch of new VARCHARs or whatever.

2) Create a "use_case" column in the "Image" table and assign the corresponding ID from the "UseCase" table above per image.

3) Create a hasOne/belongsTo relationship between "Image" and "UseCase" on UseCase.id = Image.use_case

4) Create a scope in your "Customer" table something like below...

```
public function scopeUseCase($query, $case){
    $query->with(['Image.UseCase' => function($relationQuery) use ($case) {
         return $relationQuery->where('name', '=', $case);
    }]);
}
```

5) Finally, reference the cases by name in queries using the scope like so...

```
Customer::useCase('logo')->get();
```

Should be a pretty clean and straightforward process from there.  Sorry for formatting issues stuck on mobile.

Comment: While this approach could work - it would significantly increase query complexity and cause certain issues with relations - unless relations were omitted entirely.

Comment: You're right.  Middle-ground would be loading the UseCase table in another variable and referencing the values from that rather than eager loading through two relations.

Comment: Yes, exactly @SavvyK